# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native' - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have just started learning React Native and wanted to add input fields to the page. I have gone through [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_text.htm) to add input fields. But whenever I run the React App it throws the following error.

```
./src/Inputs.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native' in 'E:\hybrid\reactDemo\src'
```

I have checked if the react-native node-modules is there or not, then I came to know that the module react-native was not there. I installed it run the app again, but it shows the same error.  I have spent more than 8 hours on this but unable to resolve this error. I have tried out all the solution from google but none of them worked for me.

**Note:** **I am using windows PC**

**Update 1:** I am importing react-native like following

```
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
```

**Update 2:**

This is my package.json file

```
{    
  "name": "reactDemo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.54.4",
    "react-router": "^3.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you importing `react-native`?

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani - I have updated my question

Comment: please add your package.json and webpack.config.js/other build tool config. looks like it's trying to find `react-native` in `<root>/src` while it should be looking in `<root>/node_modules`

Answer (score 31):

I'm not sure but in my case it helped to install react native web by `npm install react-native-web`. Hope it helps you too.

Comment: It really helps! I guess this is one of the dependency of `react-native`.

Comment: `react-native-web` is not a dependency of `react-native`, but if you make a web build of a react-native project, webpack/babel/etc use an alias under the hood to hijack every import of `react-native` and point them at `react-native-web` instead. So if `react-native-web` isn't installed, the `react-native` import will fail because it has been aliased to point somewhere that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 13):

Your project can't see the react-native package. If you already have all required dependencies installed (for use of react-native) go the end of this post. if not, I **suggest** you have the following:

1. **react-scripts:** contains the scripts used in create-react-app.
2. **react-dom:** allows react-code to be rendered into an HTML page
3. **react-native-web:** the main source of magic in this app. This library will convert our react-native components into web elements.
4. **react-art:** a peer dependency for react-native-web
5. **react-router-native:** routing library for React Native
6. **react-router-dom:** routing library for React on the web

========================================================================

First thing first, you need compatible babel-jest dependencies. To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in
   your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "babel-jest" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

The above configuration do not require you to have webpack manually configured, because react-scripts does that.

Maybe you don't use all that nor even react-scripts, so you must have to configure your webpack.config.js. To fix this, try the following:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = ({platform}, defaults) => ({
  ...defaults,
  entry: './index.js',
  /* ... */
  resolve: {
    ...defaults.resolve,
    alias: {
       ...defaults.resolve.alias,
      react: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/react'),
      'react-native': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-native'),
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Actually adding those 6 packages fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

To add web support to an existing Expo app you can do the following:

1. Install the latest version of the Expo CLI: `npm i -g expo-cli`
2. Add web dependencies: `yarn add react-native-web react-dom`
3. Startup faster in web-only mode by running `expo start:web` You can also run `expo start --web` which will start Webpack immediately.

Source https://docs.expo.io/guides/running-in-the-browser/

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add react-native in other react project. React Native is like React, but it uses native components instead of web components as building blocks.
So install react-native using *npm install -g react-native-cli* in a new folder and then initiate new react-native project using *react-native init ProjectName*.

Run *react-native run-ios / run-android* inside your React Native project folder

[Reference](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced a similar issue after upgrading Webpack, for me performing a clean install will resolve it.

`npm ci`

Answer (score 0):

File path doesn't mention correctly. Please check it again. Issue is in your external import of the files in src directory and confirm that the file is in the mentioned path.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend **EXPO** which by just one command sets up everything necessary for writing react-native locally.
First dowmload the expo-cli;
In your command line;

```
npm install expo-cli --global
```

After it gets installed, run this command to create a project;

```
expo init name_of_project
```

That is it. Everything will be done and now you just have to start writing some code.

Answer (score 0):

Just running `npm install` inside the main app folder, solved it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

i have been create project by  expo init name_of_project
and it runs on web as well but when i add  mapbox by this command
npm install @react-native-mapbox-gl/maps   --save
i have some errors

./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/AssetSourceResolver.js:24:17
Module not found: Can't resolve '../Utilities/Platform'
22 |
23 | const PixelRatio = require('../Utilities/PixelRatio');

> 24 | const Platform = require('../Utilities/Platform');
> |                 ^
> 25 |
> 26 | const invariant = require('invariant');
> 27 |

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30615769)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue since many days **"Module not found"** the simple solution is go to your project folder and delete **node_modules** folder and then try i hope this answer is helpful for you thank you.

Comment: still facing issue after deleting node_modules please also delete npm-cache folder go to C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/npm-cache and delete it will working fine.